# HibQuerySyntaxException when I use CAST() in query

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am running this hibernate query from my java class.But i am getting QuerySyntaxException.But i didnt find any thing went wrong.

Query

```
SELECT count(contact.id) 
FROM Contact contact 
WHERE contact.id  IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT action.contact 
    FROM Action action 
    WHERE action.status = 'O' 
    AND action.currentAssignee = :currentAssignee) 
AND contact.contactStatus IN :contactStatus
AND CAST(contact.id as char(12)) like :id           --Note this line
AND contact.issue.productGroup IN :productGroup
```

But the problem is in using CAST.

**The error is** :

*expecting CLOSE, found '('
 
Error While getting countOpenContacts. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '('*

The following java code has been used to set the id.(contact.id is Long value and contactId is string.)

```
query.append("AND CAST(contact.id as char(12)) like :id ");
params.put("id",(contactId+ "%"));
```

Can we CAST in hibernate query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions) says, we can use

```
cast(... as ...), where the second argument is the name of a Hibernate type
```

So you should try

```
AND CAST(contact.id as string) like :id
```

Comment: Many many thanks.Thats very big help.Thank you very much Eugene.